# Best practice for running two concurrent processes in C (on a Raspberry Pi)

Tags: c, mp3, raspberry-pi, ncurses

I'm programming a "simple" jukebox in C which is to run on a Raspberry Pi and I'm having difficulties in figuring out what's the best way to optimize its performance.

The way it is set up is that I have one process which handles all the graphics (via ncurses) and data handling, and another which i send commands to an mp3-playing application(xmms2) with and then I connect the two with two pipes to form a simple bridge which sends messages like "get current playlist position" and responds with "current playlist position: 0" (although not as verbose as that).

All pipes are set to be non-blocking, but I still experience a lot of lag when sending these commands.

Realize this may be a bit of an abstract question, but I'm not super well versed in C and would appreciate any type of input as to wether or not I've gone in entirely the wrong direction or not with how this is set up.

Thanks in advance!

main loop:

```
init_xmms_bridge();

pid_t pid = fork();

while(true == true)
{
    update_xmms_bridge(pid);
    if(pid != 0)
        update_screen();
}
```

graphics.c

```
void update_screen(void)
{
    /* update playlist if that has changed, 
    library display if keys has been pressed etc */

    usleep(50000); // Wait .05 seconds
    refresh(); // Refresh ncurses screen
}
```

xmms_bridge.c (partial)

```
void init_xmms_bridge(void)
{
    pipe(xmms_pipe_in);
    pipe(xmms_pipe_out);

    // Set all pipes as non-blocking
    int flags = fcntl(xmms_pipe_in[0], F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(xmms_pipe_in[0], F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

    flags = fcntl(xmms_pipe_in[1], F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(xmms_pipe_in[1], F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

    flags = fcntl(xmms_pipe_out[0], F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(xmms_pipe_out[0], F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

    flags = fcntl(xmms_pipe_out[1], F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(xmms_pipe_out[1], F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

}

// Receive data from pipes
void update_xmms_bridge(pid_t process_id)
{
    if(process_id == 0) // Child process
    {
        close(xmms_pipe_out[1]);
        bytes_read_out = read(xmms_pipe_out[0],xmms_pipe_buffer_out,sizeof(xmms_pipe_buffer_out));

        if(bytes_read_out != -1)
            xmms_receive_call(xmms_pipe_buffer_out,XMMSDirectionOut);
    }
    else
    {
        close(xmms_pipe_in[1]);
        bytes_read_in = read(xmms_pipe_in[0],xmms_pipe_buffer_in,sizeof(xmms_pipe_buffer_in));

        if(bytes_read_in != -1)
            xmms_receive_call(xmms_pipe_buffer_in,XMMSDirectionIn);
    }
}

// Send data to pipes
void bridge_call(int pipe[2],const char command,char *parameters)
{
    // Make sure it works even if parameters is null
    char call[parameters == NULL ? 3 : strlen(parameters)+3];

    /* Add separator to deal with the fact
    that multiple calls can be made before 
    the loop reads the pipe. */
    call[0] = SEPARATOR_CHARACTER;
    call[1] = command;
    call[2] = '\0';

    // Concentate string before sending through pipe
    if(parameters != NULL)
        strcat(call,parameters);

    close(pipe[0]);
    write(pipe[1],call,strlen(call));
}

void xmms_bridge_call(const char command,char *parameters)
{
    bridge_call(xmms_pipe_out,command,parameters);
}

void jukebox_bridge_call(const char command,char *parameters)
{
    bridge_call(xmms_pipe_in,command,parameters);
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `close` in the `update_xmms_bridge` function? Do it once *outside* the loop instead.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I close it because I open it every time a message is sent to those pipes, sorry perhaps it's a bit unclear since I omitted that function, and I guess your answer still works since I could close the pipe immedieatly after it was opened and written to by the other function. I'll add the other function for clarity.

Comment: You don't need to create and recreate pipes for every message, just create the pipes once, and keep sending/receiving on them in the processes.

Comment: The pi is a single-core device. There will be no performance gains from making a multithreaded program. Threads will be more of design choice for you.

Comment: @Kenneth thanks for your answer, that's exactly the type of thing that I wasn't even thinking of. So basically I'll have to work around the fact that some processes will be blocking no matter what I do?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg hmmm does your answer still stand with seeing the edits I made? I was under the impression that you need to close the input of a pipe to access the output and vice versa?

Comment: No, a pipe is like a water pipe. You write data on one end of the pipe, and data comes out at the other end, and it streams along the pipe as long as you keep sending data and don't close the end-points. And it's completely asynchronous.

Comment: @AndreasJensSylvester No that's not what it will mean. The advantage of using threads is that you are allowed to wait for some processes while doing other tasks as long as you are waiting in a different thread. The processor will just only be able to perform a single task at a time. I would still opt for the threaded design as it is easier to think tasks in relative priority rather than absolute time. And it is alway, alway preferable to not mix application and presentation code.

Comment: @Kenneth oh fork, guess I've got some studying to do then, thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Kenneth by the way if you are concerned with your "reputation", you're free to add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it :¬)

Comment: I'm not so sure exactly what my answer would be. I would recommend that you tried to best solve your lag issues and then post the steps you took here. It is perfectly acceptable to answer your own question on this site.

Comment: @Kenneth good point, I'll do that!

Comment: Why aren't you using the xmms2 C client library that takes care of all of this for you?

Comment: @Craig I actually tried to find one early on but somehow didn't, but looking for it now I found it almost instantly? Past me obviously deserves a slap. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading up on what user Kenneth pointed out, I solved this by replacing the process forking with threads. Since most my calls were supposed to be one way, my typical thread code looked like this:

```
pthread_t thread;
pthread_attr_t thread_attr;
int thread_error;

thread_error = pthread_attr_init(&thread);

if(thread_error)
{
    /* Handle error */
    return;
}

/* Make thread detached so I don't need to worry about it after it's creation */
result = pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&thread_attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

if(!thread_error)
{
    thread_error = pthread_create(&thread,&thread_attr,<xmms-calling-funtion>,<arguments>);

    pthread_attr_destroy(&thread_attr);

    if(thread_error)
        /* Handle error */
}
else
    /* Handle error */
```

As user Craig mentioned, there is a xmms2 C client library, but I never managed to link it to my program although I'm sure it would have been preferable to have used it. I still feel that this answer pertains more to my question which was more about performance on the Raspberry Pi than xmms2 specifically though.

If anyone does build a project on a Raspberry Pi and manages to successfully link it to the xmms2 C client library, I would love to hear how you did it!

Link to the client library tutorial repository:

```
git://git.xmms2.org/xmms2/xmms2-tutorial.git
```

For curious people, this is what the user interface ended up looking like:

[image: Picture of Raspberry Pi based jukebox running ncurses]